# How to get n rows of a large excel sheet in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, fs, js-xlsx

I am getting excel data in buffer format to nodejs.
I have to read this data and send the headers and first 1000 records back as a response.

I have tried the below code

This is my router file, where I am using multer

```
 const express = require("express");
 const router = express.Router();
 var multer  = require('multer')();
 const uploadDocument = require("./RA/UploadDocument")

router.post("/uploadDocument", multer.single('slicedFile'), uploadDocument)
```

Below is the uploadDocument file where I have concatenated the chunks received from frontend

```
 const XLSX = require('xlsx') 
 var buffer = [];
buffer.push(req.file.buffer);
if(req.body.isLastBlob==='true'){
    let buf = Buffer.concat(buffer);
    var base64 = (buf.toString('base64'));
    var pre="data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,";
    base64 = pre+base64;
    buffer = [];  

    var docdata = base64.split(',').pop();
    var bufdata = Buffer.from(docdata, 'base64');
      
      let wb= XLSX.read(bufdata, {type: "buffer", sheetRows: 1});
      const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
      const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];
      const fileheaders = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, { header: 1 });

      let wb_rows= XLSX.read(bufdata, {type: "buffer", sheetRows: 100});
      const wsname_rows = wb_rows.SheetNames[0];
      const ws_rows = wb_rows.Sheets[wsname_rows];
      const rows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws_rows);
  }
```

This code is working fine for small files which have upto 50000 rows. It is giving meheader name and the value like below

```
[
  {
    'Name': 'Charge',
    'Region': 'Region 1',
    'Country': 'SA',
    'Pin Code': '100000',
     .....
}]
```

But when I try the same code for large file which is having upto 1000000 records it is giving me incorrect data as below.

[
{
'0': 'Charge',
'1': 100,
'24': 1,
'41': 100,
'119': 18513,
'204': 2186439862,
'378': 'Subscription Fees',
'18511': 27964203,
'40131818': 115,
'111716467': 115,
__EMPTY: 'SAF',
'1/28/22': 'South Africa',
'Add-on Subscription': 44591.0577662037,
'1/28/22_1': 204,
'2/27/22': 41,
'.0000': 70168816
}

Comment: I think when parsing 1000000 records, system memory is behaving weirdly. Try to cut down parsing in chuncks rather than in 1 go.